# Error de conexion php y dbisam

Tags: php, odbc

Mi problema es el siguiente estoy tratando de conectarme a una base de datos dbisam mediante php pero no he podido hacer una consulta ya descargue el controlador ODBC para dbisam, estos son los errores que me dan:

> Warning: odbc_connect(): in C:\xampp\htdocs\DBISAM.php on line 13
>
> Warning: odbc_exec() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\DBISAM.php on line 39
>
> Warning: odbc_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\DBISAM.php on line 41

este es mi script completo

```
 <?php

class DBISAM {
    
    // set folder here
    static $folder = "C:/xampp/htdocs/Data";
    static $db;
    
    // Connect to ODBC source
    public static function Connect() {

        $db = odbc_connect("DRIVER={DBISAM 4 ODBC Driver};ConnectionType=Local;CatalogName=".self::$folder.";","admin","");
        self::$db = $db;
        return $db;
    }
    
    // Escape a string
    public static function Escape($data) {
        if ( !isset($data) or empty($data) ) return '';
        if ( is_numeric($data) ) return $data;

        $non_displayables = array(
            '/%0[0-8bcef]/',            // url encoded 00-08, 11, 12, 14, 15
            '/%1[0-9a-f]/',             // url encoded 16-31
            '/[\x00-\x08]/',            // 00-08
            '/\x0b/',                   // 11
            '/\x0c/',                   // 12
            '/[\x0e-\x1f]/'             // 14-31
        );
        foreach ( $non_displayables as $regex )
        $data = preg_replace( $regex, '', $data );
        $data = str_replace("'", "''", $data );
        return $data;
    }

    // Get all data from an ODBC query, into an array
    public static function GetAll($query,$key="") {
        $res = odbc_exec(self::$db,$query);
        $result = array();
        while($row=odbc_fetch_array($res)) {
            if ($key)
                $result[$row[$key]] = $row;
            else
                $result[] = $row;
        }        
        return $result;
    }
    
    
    // Run an ODCB query
    public static function Query($query) {
        $res = odbc_exec(self::$db, $query);
        return $res;
    }
        
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Te está fallando la llamada a odbc_connect, fijate que tengas bien los parámetros (ruta, usuario, contraseña, etc.). Para descartar errores podés probar establecer la conexión desde Excel por ejemplo.

Comment: como me recomendaste probé la conexión con excel y perfecto cuando intento establecer la conexion desde php no lo hace ya los errores no se muestran pero no me sale mas nada si no que se queda cargando el navegador

Answer (score 0):

Estas definiendo tu función `Connect()` pero no la estas llamando para definir los parámetros de conexión. Simplemente mandala llamar antes de realizar `odbc_exec()` para que `$db` tenga el valor apropiado :

```
Connect();
 $res = odbc_exec(self::$db,$query);
```